# Revocation Status Unknown error when generating X.509 certificate in BouncyCastle

Tags: java, security, x509certificate, bouncycastle, digital-certificate

New to encryption and security and trying to generate a x509 Certificate.

Tried the following code which is using BouncyCastle API:

```
X509V3CertificateGenerator certGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
System.out.println("- ---Inside createCertificate Method----- certificate generated");
certGenerator.setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(Math.abs(new Random().nextLong())));
certGenerator.setIssuerDN(new X509Name(dn));
certGenerator.setSubjectDN(new X509Name(dn));
certGenerator.setIssuerDN(new X509Name(issuer)); // Set issuer!
Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) certGenerator.generate(
                    privateKey, "BC");
```

And run into the exception.

```
security: The OCSP support is enabled
security: The CRL support is enabled
security: Failing over to CRLs: Certificate does not specify OCSP responder
security: Revocation Status Unknown
com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker$StatusUnknownException: Certificate does not specify OCSP responder
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker.checkOCSP(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.checkRevocationStatus(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.getValidationState(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.validateChain(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.isAllPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.isTrustedByTrustDecider(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.getTrustedCodeSources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.strategy(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.openClassPathElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Suppressed: com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker$StatusUnknownException
        at com.sun.deploy.security.RevocationChecker.checkCRLs(Unknown Source)
        ... 54 more
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
```

Tried to google, no clues on this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to BouncyCastle and the certificate generation. You are using a Java applet and the java plugin is trying to validate the JAR files signatures. However it seems that the signature certificate (or one of the certificate in the certificate chain) does not have the suitable extensions containing the CRL server or OCSP responder URL. Therefore the signature validation fails and the JAR cannot be used.

One solution could be deactivate the certificate validation in the Java Control Center (in the Advanced tab, "Perform certificate revocation checks on" option, select no validation). Note that this is **NOT RECOMMENDED** for a day-to-day usage but acceptable for testing purpose (for instance during development when the applet is signed with a development/self-signed certificate).

Comment: I found the same problem running the Java version checker on Java.com. `https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp` http://java.com:8080. Does that mean that Java screwed up issuing their cert or jar?